# unable to update a subdocuments in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

im trying to update a value for uid in solts.slots but nothing works.
i want to iterate two level of array to modify the document

```
{
"_id": {
  "$oid": "638455dee12f0122c9812697"
},
"bid": "637b0fdd3d9a96eb913805d3",
"name": "sucess",

"slots": [
  {
    "date": "2022-11-28T00:00:00.000Z",
    "slots": [
      
      {
        "uid": null,
        "available": true,
        "status": null,
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "638455dee12f0122c98126a0"
        }
      },
      {
        "uid": null,
        "available": true,
        "status": null,
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "638455dee12f0122c98126a1"
        }
      }
      
    ],
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "638455dee12f0122c9812698"
    }
  }   
    ]}]}
```

im trying to update the slots for id `638455dee12f0122c98126a0` properties like

- uid:'234235'
- available:false
- status:'booked'

can anyone help me to query this

i tried

```
const result = await Event.findOne({
        'slots.slots': {
            $elemMatch: {
                _id: req.body.id
            }
        }
    })
```

is there is any way to query this type of documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$[]` and `$[<identifier>]`:

```
db.collection.update({
  "slots.slots": {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: ObjectId("638455dee12f0122c98126a0")
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "slots.$[].slots.$[item].available": false,
    "slots.$[].slots.$[item].uid": "234235",
    "slots.$[].slots.$[item].status": "booked"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "item._id": ObjectId("638455dee12f0122c98126a0")
    }
  ]
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7lNU02Jm8xI)

Comment: {"acknowledged":true,"modifiedCount":0,"upsertedId":null,"upsertedCount":0,"matchedCount":1}

Comment: not updated i dont know why

Comment: Is the playground example working for you? Can you provide an example that does not work?

Comment: its working completly fine in playground. but im using mongoose driver for nodejs that shows the above result as modifiedcount : 0

Comment: your code working fine in mongosh but not in mongoose.js

Comment: after changing the `ObjectId('xxxxxxx')` to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('xxxxxxxx')` it works !! its my mistake and without your code it is not possible thanks alot

Comment: is it possible to get the only updated subdocument ?

Comment: Sure, just use [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/) instead of `update`. You can control if you want to get back the document before or after the update